# jQuery UI menu, how to access options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

How does one access a menu selection in jQuery UI? I'm used to forms like the following:

```
<form>
<select onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="1">Option 1</option>
<option value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Accessing the form is then done using:

```
function showUser(str) {
    if (str=="1"){
      // do something
   }
}
```

But, the jQuery UI form doesn't seem to have a function attached to it, so I am not sure how to access selections.

Here is the jQuery UI menu code (from http://jqueryui.com/menu/#categories):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Menu - Categories</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu({
      items: "> :not(.ui-widget-header)"
    });
  });
  </script>
  <style>
  .ui-menu { width: 200px; }
  .ui-widget-header { padding: 0.2em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<ul id="menu">
  <li class="ui-widget-header">Category 1</li>
  <li>Option 1</li>
  <li>Option 2</li>
  <li>Option 3</li>
  <li class="ui-widget-header">Category 2</li>    
  <li>Option 4</li>
  <li>Option 5</li>
  <li>Option 6</li>
</ul>
```

How does one access each option like in the previous example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
$('#menu').menu({
    select: function(event, ui) {
        alert(ui.item.text());
    }
});
```

jQuery UI's `menu` has a `select` method where you can access the event and the UI widget. This adds an event listener, whereby you have access to the data.

Comment: Please include an explanation as to why this should work, as the code itself may solve the problem but it is not self-evident to all future viewers of this question.

Comment: Thanks, how do I access this later in the code? In my previous example, I use if (str=="1"){ do something }.